# google custom search results shows in popup instead of page in php

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I am using google custom search in my site. It wis working fine for me. Only problem is it shows me results in popup instead of my given url Here is my code.

```
<div class="navbar-right" id="search-bar" >
    <script>
        (function() {
          var cx = '006045053715355086088:qma4ulxxwhu';
          var gcse = document.createElement('script');
          gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
          gcse.async = true;
          gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
              '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
      </script>
      <gcse:search resultsUrl="http://localhost/barbadosparliament/result/index/"></gcse:search>
    </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me why it is shows me results in popup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '006045053715355086088:qma4ulxxwhu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search linktarget="_parent" resultsUrl="http://localhost/barbadosparliament/result/index/"></gcse:search>
```

Comment: So, what's the difference?  I see a `linktarget="_parent"` in yours; is anything else changed?

Comment: If you try with `cx=003074870824758447082:b7qmpwpireg` It shows the results in same window. I think it depends on Custom Search Engine specification

Comment: Go through the link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/o4loA9VEfX0/RbIz8XiNc50J

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the settings in your Google "Custom Search" console

In the "Look and feel" menu, Pick one of the choices on this page that is not an overlay

https://cse.google.com